# how to fetch records equal to pageSize while using queryForCursor in SolrTemplate

Tags: solr

I want to fetch records from solr using cursors as I have large resultset size.
I m using SolrTemplate.queryForCursor() method by passing query object to this. But the resultCursor which is of type Cursor has all data in it. I want to stop reading from cursor when my pageSize is hit.

```
Criteria query = new Criteria("UserName").is ("abc");
query.setRows(10); // As i want to have fetch 10 records at a time
Cursor<T> resultCusrsor = solrTemplate.queryForCursor(query,Entity.class);
while(resultCursor.hasNext() ){
System.out.println( "Result : " + resultCusrsor.next());
}
```

The while loop here keeps printing all records by fetching 10 at a time. If my pagesize is 100, I want to fetch 10 records 10 times using cursor, but how do I stop at 100th record?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply keep a counter for fetched items and terminate once page size is reached.

```
    int pageSize = 100, rows = 10, currSize = 0;
    Criteria query = new Criteria("UserName").is("abc");
    query.setRows(rows); // As i want to have fetch 10 records at a time
    Cursor<T> resultCusrsor = solrTemplate.queryForCursor(query, Entity.class);
    while (resultCursor.hasNext() && currSize < pageSize) {
        System.out.println("Result : " + resultCusrsor.next());
        currSize = currSize + rows;
    }
```